# Xamarin Android ListView select item and change row color

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new to xamarin and I've been looking everywhere for a way to select an item in a ListView and change the color of the row to let the user know which row is selected. Here is what I got

```
    private void FormsListViewOnItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs itemClickEventArgs)
    {
        _cicoListView.SetItemChecked(itemClickEventArgs.Position, true);
        for (var i = 0; i < _ciCos.Count; i++)
        {
            if (itemClickEventArgs.Position == i)
            {
                _selectedId = ((CicoModel)_cicoListView.Adapter.GetItem(i)).Pk;
                //_formsListView.SetItemChecked(itemClickEventArgs.Position, true);   
            }
            _cicoListView.GetChildAt(i)?.SetBackgroundColor(itemClickEventArgs.Position == i ? Color.LightGray : Color.Transparent);
        }
    }
```

This method is the click handler of the item

```
 _cicoListView.ItemClick += FormsListViewOnItemClick;
```

The only problem I have is when I scroll down other items are selected too because (it's my best guess) the list view recycles the rows and the positions. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ListView Adapter GetView method (or in your RecyclerView Adapter OnBindViewHolder method), insert the code as follows:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //inflate or restore convertView
    if(this.myItems[position].selected == true)
    {
        convertView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Green);
    }
    convertView.Click -= ChangeBackgroundColor;
    convertView.Click += ChangeBackgroundColor;
    // This is to avoid adding more than one EventHandler every time the View is shown in the ListView.
}

private void ChangeBackgroundColor(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int position = this.recyclerView.GetChildAdapterPosition((View)sender);
    this.myItems[position].selected = true;
    ((View)sender).SetBackgroundColor(Color.Green);
}
```

You can also do that by using a custom drawable for background, like in this question:

[Android: set list view item as "selected" (highlighted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742269/android-set-list-view-item-as-selected-highlighted)